# nginx: unable to perform path based routing

Tags: docker, nginx

I am creating a `docker-compose` stack with `prometheus`, `grafana` and `nginx`.

I want to provide host-based routing so that the `/` location redirects to `grafana` and `/prometheus` to `prometheus`.

However the `nginx.conf` below, does perofmrm `/` --> `grafana` redirection but not `/prometheus` --> `prometheus` (the later goes to a `grafana` error page)

Any suggestions?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;


    server_name _;


    location /prometheus  {
        rewrite ^/prometheus(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://11.12.12.31:9090;
    }

    location / {    
        proxy_pass http://11.12.12.31:3000;
    }
```

(`prometheus` and `grafana` are services exposed to `9090` and `3000` respectively)

**edit**:

```
nginx_1          | 199.99.99.67 - - [17/Jan/2019:11:10:51 +0000] "GET /prometheus HTTP/1.1" 302 29 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" "-"
grafana_1        | t=2019-01-17T11:10:51+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/graph status=404 remote_addr=192.168.96.1 time_ms=8 size=25545 referer=
nginx_1          | 199.99.99.67 - - [17/Jan/2019:11:10:51 +0000] "GET /graph HTTP/1.1" 404 25581 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: How to access prometheus through `http://11.12.12.31:9090`? Does it include any uri, or just `http://11.12.12.31:9090` is okay?

Comment: Yes `http://11.12.12.31:9090` takes you to `prometheus`

Comment: Could you share some error logs or other access logs?

Comment: updated with logs when trying to access `<public_ip>/prometheus`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `rewrite ^/prometheus(.*) /$1 break;` clause is causing a redirection to `/`.

The `nginx` documentation suggests that the `rewrite` operation actually performs an regular expression against the requested `url` and replace it with something else.

In this case `/prometheus/` is been resolved as `/` due to regex `(.*)`. This expression means to match **0 or more** characters after the word "prometheus" and to capture/store whatever characters found as variable `$1`.

So path `/prometheus` is been replaced as `/` which brings you to the `Grafana` server.

Removing the `rewrite` rule will fix your problem.

**Reference:**

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

https://regex101.com/r/vjbFdN/1

Comment: I incorporated the `rewrite` rule because if I don't I am afraid the `/prometheus` part is forwarded in the request path so it ends up forming a request in the likes of `http://11.12.12.31:9090/prometheus` (which of course does not exist). Reference here: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

Comment: Users shouldn't be allowed to access your services directly through the port. To prevent this your nginx should only be forwarding port `80` for `http` and `443` for `https`. Also make sure `Grafana` and `Prometheus` services don't forward any ports. Port forwarding is done via the `ports` attribute of the services in `docker-compose` file. Typically you would also be writing `firewall` rules to seal up unused ports to prevent them from been exploit.